# SwiftUI different maxWidth between elements in a Stack

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, swiftui

I want to have a view that shows two elements created with a customShape (it is basically the same Shape as RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius:25.0) but combined with a normal rectangle to make 2 corners sharped). The problem is that when I try to combine these two views (miking it a Capsule() I am not able to modify its proportion. I'd like the image to occupy only the 25% of the pill and the text the 75% lasting. But I am not able to accomplish this. This is a photo of what i have : [image: View shown]

And what I want to have: [image: View expected]

I tried using GeometryReader but I don't know if it is a good solution or if I don't know how to use it but I get this: [image: View using GeometryReader]

The code of the main view is:

```swift
struct CardHomeContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/25.0/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            HStack(spacing:0) { //Contenido
                ImageContent(image:"Croissant")
                TextCardContent()
            }
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

ImageView is:

```swift
struct ImageContent: View {
    let image : String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
        }
    }
}
```

And the TextView:

```swift
struct TextCardContent: View {
    let uiFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 13)
    let description = "Unos croissants que harán chuparte los dedos llenos de mantequilla"
    var justifiedTest: String {
        description.justified(font: uiFont, maxWidth: 165)
    }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangleCustomShapeRight().foregroundStyle(Color.white)
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Text("Croissants tradicionales").bold().lineLimit(2).minimumScaleFactor(0.4)
                    Text(description).font(.footnote).foregroundStyle(Color.gray).lineLimit(3).minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                }
                .padding(.all)
                Text(">")
                    .padding(.trailing)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

So I would appreciate if someone could come up with any idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fixing the height and the width of the card views then there is an easy solution: you just need to wrap the shape with a `GeometryReader`, as explained in another answer.

However, if you want the cards to adopt a natural height, it's a bit more tricky. Here are two techniques:

**1. Use a hidden footprint with an overlay**

- The footprint (in particular, the height) is established using hidden content. The text part can probably be used for this purpose.
- Ideally, dummy text (perhaps containing newlines) should be used for finding the footprint, so that the height of the footprint is always the same for all instances.
- The overlay contains a `GeometryReader`, which measures the size of the footprint.
- A clip shape with rounded corners can be applied to the overall composition. This way, it is not necessary to apply a half-rounded rectangle to the text part.

```swift
struct CardHomeContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextCardContent()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .hidden()
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader { proxy in
                    HStack(spacing:0) { //Contenido
                        ImageContent(image: "Croissant")
                            .frame(width: proxy.size.width / 4)
                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .clipped()
                        TextCardContent()
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                            .background(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
    }
}

struct ImageContent: View {
    // as betore
}

struct TextCardContent: View {
    let description = "Unos croissants que harán chuparte los dedos llenos de mantequilla"

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Croissants tradicionales")
                    .bold()
                    .lineLimit(2)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.4)
                Text(description)
                    .font(.footnote)
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.gray)
                    .lineLimit(3)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }
            .padding()
            Text(">")
                .padding(.trailing)
        }
    }
}
```

By default, `CardHomeContent` will grab as much width as possible, because the footprint uses `maxWidth: .infinity`. The width can be constrained by applying a `frame` to `CardHomeContent`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.gray
            CardHomeContent()
                .frame(width: 350)
        }
    }
}
```

**2. Use a custom layout**

Another way to solve the problem is using a custom `Layout`. In the following example implementation, the layout is only expecting to have two subviews and the height of the overall card is determined by the second of the subviews:

```swift
struct CardLayout: Layout {
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let w = proposal.width ?? 100
        var h = CGFloat.zero
        if subviews.count == 2, let lastSubview = subviews.last {
            let subviewSize = lastSubview.sizeThatFits(.init(width: w * 3 / 4, height: proposal.height))
            h = subviewSize.height
        }
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        if let w = proposal.width, subviews.count == 2,
           let firstSubview = subviews.first, let lastSubview = subviews.last {
            let subviewSize = lastSubview.sizeThatFits(.init(width: w * 3 / 4, height: proposal.height))
            let h = subviewSize.height
            firstSubview.place(
                at: bounds.origin,
                proposal: .init(width: w / 4, height: h)
            )
            lastSubview.place(
                at: CGPoint(x: bounds.minX + bounds.width / 4, y: bounds.minY),
                proposal: .init(width: w * 3 / 4, height: h)
            )
        }
    }
}

struct CardHomeContent: View {
    var body: some View {
        CardLayout { //Contenido
            ImageContent(image: "Croissant")
                .clipped()
            TextCardContent()
                .background(.white)
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
    }
}

// ImageContent, TextCardContent and ContentView as before
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Answer updated to show how a custom layout could be used too

Comment: So, whenever do I want to combine views inside a Layout (int this case RoundedRectangle(). Do I create an infinityView as hidden and put my subView in the Overlay? Because what I have done until now is using a ZStack {} to put the main view as background and then the subView.

Comment: An overlay automatically adopts the size of the view it is applied to. Inside the overlay, a `GeometryReader` can be used to measure this size. So an overlay is a useful technique for cases where the top layer should stay within the bounds of the bottom layer and, especially, when the size needs to be known. The difference to a `ZStack` is that each layer in a `ZStack` is free to find its own size and the size of the `ZStack` itself is determined by its contents.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, the simplest way to accomplish this is to wrap CardHomeContent into a `GeometryReader`, and then calculate the width of each card view part. i.e, ImageContent has 0.25 and TextCardContent will take 0.75, of the total width.

```swift
var body: some View {
   ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
        GeometryReader { geo in //<- Here
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ImageContent(image: "Croissant")
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.25) //<- Here

                TextCardContent()
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width * 0.75) //<- Here
            }
        }
    }
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
    .padding(.horizontal)
}
```

You also can remove ZStack in `ImageContent`, since it was an Image only and its parent is a ZStack already. However, ImageContent need to change to `scaledToFit` or you can keep `scaledToFill` with `clipped()`, to avoid overwhelming.